# The member 'setState' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart'

Tags: flutter

(i18n) I use setState from outside of MyApp class to change language, I got this warning, and don't know how to solve it.

```
info: The member 'setState' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart'. (invalid_use_of_protected_member at [flutter_firebase_authen] lib\app.dart:22)
```

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer;

  const MyApp({
    Key key,
    @required this.observer,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();

  static void setLocale(BuildContext context, Locale newLocale) {
    final _MyAppState state = context.ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher<_MyAppState>());
    state.setState(() {
      state.locale = newLocale;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: try: Don't use static and final.

Answer (score 14):

The warning message is quite clear: the function `setState` should only be called from within the class, not from another class.

The workaround is simple, write a helper function inside your `State` class, that calls `setState` for you. For example:

```
refresh() => setState(() {});
```

Now from outside this class, you can call `state.refresh()`.

(But really, if you are calling `setState` from another class, maybe you should look into `ValueNotifier`, or `StreamBuilder`, etc.)

Comment: I got this error: `Instance member 'refresh' can't be accessed using static access.`