# Why should I only use `setState` in subclasses of `framework.dart`?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have written and extension on `Stream` that allows me to call `.watch(<some state>)` and automatically keep the widget updated. It works really well, however, I call `setState` on passed states from the extension and because of this I get a warning saying `The member 'setState' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart'`. My question is **why is this not recommended/allowed?**. To clarify, I get why I am getting the warning - I'm calling `setState` from another class - but *why does Flutter "care"* if I do this?

I have tried to find information on any reason for this, but I can only find the obvious workaround of adding a helper function, and no reason is given.

Answer (score 1):

There could be two possible reasons why you are getting this error:

- You are using a static or final keyword somewhere where you declare a state
- You are unable to setState, because the extension is updating the state of the widget already

Let me know if you need any further help or I understood you wrong!

Comment: You might also want to check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58669033/the-member-setstate-can-only-be-used-within-instance-members-of-subclasses-of)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tried to update my question to clarify what I mean. I understand why I'm getting the warning: I'm intentionally calling `setState` from a different object. My question is why Flutter warns about doing this. Is there something that leaves this undesirable?

Comment: There are two things I can propose here. The first being that they might be trying to keep state internal meaning within the object although I would agree that it might be nice to setStates from another object which leads me to my second proposal of Flutter might be trying to promote a way of using states "correctly" and possibly optimally as well as reduce the complexity of the state management.